# how to references rulenames in a child component in jss

Tags: material-ui, jss

I'm using `Material-UI`. As it supports CSS styling with JSS, I'm struggling to access rule names in a different component. As you see the below codes, `MyComponent` uses `AppBar` component and I need to access rule names in `AppBar` component. However, for some reason I can't access the rule names in it.

**MyComponent.js**

```
<div id="navigation-pills">
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <AppBar position="static" color="default">
      <Tabs
        ...
      >
        ...
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
  </div>
</div>
```

**styles.js**

```
const styles = theme => ({
  ...
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    "& $flexContainer": {
      display: "none"
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

[JSS API](http://cssinjs.org/jss-nested?v=v6.0.1#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) says that I can access child rule names with `$`, but it doesn't work for some reason.

L

Like you see the below image, I would like to access `flexContainer` rule name on line 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can only reference a rule from the same style sheet (styles object). In your code I can't tell, because you replaced it with "...".